# How to customise button ( CSS, HTML)

Tags: html, css, button, styles

I want to make a button with a picture that will be shown inside and outside the button like this: 
[image: image button]

I don't want to use image for the button, because i will have to make at least 5 images.
Is there any way to do this with css?

I am using ASP.NET & C#

Thank you

Comment: in order to do this you could use the pseudo attributes to create the button and then call the bag over the div you created the button in

Comment: Thank you for you reply. Do you have any sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the advice of marmite and solved the problem. ASP's button probably does not like the :before so i included it in a div with css class bon and styled it properly to have the outcome that i wanted.

page.aspx

```
 <div class="bon">
<asp:Button ID="AddToCartBTN" runat="server" CssClass="bot" Text="CART" OnClick="clik"/>
</div>
```

style.css

```
.bon {
    position: relative;
    padding: 6px 1em 1em 70px;       
    text-decoration: none; 
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    display:block;
    background-color: #91bd09;
    height:30px;
    z-index:100;
}
.bon:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background: url(path_to_image) no-repeat;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    z-index:999;        
}
.bon:hover
{
    background-color: #749a02;
}

.bot {
    width:100%;
    border:none;
    background-color:transparent;
    padding:5px 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px; text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);  
     cursor: pointer; 
}
```

Doing so, i can use the asp's function without having to change the way it works.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED: You can use a pseudo element on the button tag. Make the button css position: relative then you could absolutely position pseudo element inside so that it pops out the top.

Then add left padding to the button so the text doesn't sit underneath the image.

http://jsfiddle.net/j1zLb8n9/1/

```
button {
    position: relative;
    padding: 1em 1em 1em 70px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    background: #ccc;
}
button:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/60x90/3b3b3d) no-repeat;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 90px;
    width: 60px;
}
```

Comment: thank you for you reply! I tried this but i get this error:  
Error Creating Control - AddToCartBTNType 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button' does not have a public property named 'Image'.
I should have mentioned that i am using Asp.net

Comment: I updated my answer, this way you don't need to add an img tag inside the button.

Comment: I will try this and get back with the results. Thank you for the edit.

Comment: It works well with simple html button tag but it doesn't work with asp:button. Do you know why?

Comment: I have no idea about ASP I'm afraid. What markup does it generate?